# Xcode: Warning! Address of function 'calAverage will always evaluate to 'true'

Tags: c++, xcode, function, warnings

This is part of my code. I use Xcode to write my code but when I write the function into the main. My compiler starts to complain: "Address of function 'calAverage will always evaluate to 'true' ". Can someone help me a little bit about this? I am so frustrated and I don't know what is going on in my code. Thank you so much.

```
double calcAverage(int score1, int score2, int score3)
{
  double calcAverage=(score1+score2+score3)/3;
  return(calcAverage);
}



int main(）{

    double calcAverage(int score1, int score2, int score3);
    cout<<calcAverage<<setw(8); // Warning! Address of function 'calAverage will always evaluate to 'true'
}
```

Comment: Did you intend to call that function? If so you need to give it parameters: `cout<<calcAverage(2, 5, 3)<<setw(8);`

Comment: Yes. I am intending to call the function double calcAverage into the main function. What do you mean by the 2,5,3 ?